# Module parse failed: Unexpected token - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx, babel-loader

I have a project that runs a react app node server the webpack configuration for compiling the react is simple but it doesn't compile the index.js file either the runtime.js from the regenerator-runtime package

the index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import AppReducer from './reducers/AppReducer';
import AppRoutes from './containers/AppRoutes';


const store = createStore(AppReducer,compose(applyMiddleware(thunk),window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()));
const app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppRoutes />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
), app);
```

the webpack file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');


const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';

const S_PATH = __dirname + '/public/src';


module.exports = {
  mode: mode,
  devtool: (mode === 'development') ? 'inline-source-map' : false,
  entry : ['regenerator-runtime/runtime', S_PATH],
  output: {
    path : __dirname + '/public' + '/static/js',
    filename : 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: [/\.js$/], // include .js files
        enforce: 'pre', // preload the jshint loader
        exclude: /node_modules/, // exclude any and all files in the `node_modules folder`
        include: S_PATH,

        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                '@babel/preset-react',
              ],
              plugins: [
                '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
                '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
              ]
            }

          },

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

the package.json file

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=development && pm2 start ./bin/www",
    "build": "webpack --watch",
    "build-dev": "set NODE_ENV=development && webpack --watch",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.9",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.9.6",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "bcrypt": "^4.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bunyan": "^1.8.12",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "mysql2": "^1.7.0",
    "papaparse": "^5.2.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-autobind": "^1.0.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-redux-toastr": "^7.6.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "react-toastify": "^4.5.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "s": "^0.1.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.82.5",
    "sequelize": "^5.21.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "expect.js": "^0.3.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.12.1",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }

}
```

so every time run *** npm run build-dev *** it throws this error 
[image: error message]

Comment: have you fixed your issue?

Comment: not yet, I tried the same project on another PC and it worked fine 
and tried another project with a similar configuration on my PC and worked fine too